# Flutter prevent Snackbar from getting dismissed on swipe

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to prevent the `Snackbar` from dismissing when user swipes it down without making any modification in the source code of `Snackbar` class.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Not yet.

Answer (score 8):

we can use
`dismissDirection: DismissDirection.none`

code snippet:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Builder(builder: (context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => showSnackbar(context),
      child: Text("Show snackbar"),
    );
  }),
  );
}

void showSnackbar(context) {
  Scaffold.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        dismissDirection: DismissDirection.none,
        content: Text("I am here"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Placing a `GestureDetector` inside the `SnackBar` `content` and listening to `onVerticalDragStart` make it less dismissable, and using the extra `\n\n\n` makes it really annoying - but yet, dismissable. :)

In this example, it does prevent dismissing from the `content` area, but not from the SnackBar padding/margin area.

```
  void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackbar = SnackBar(
      duration: Duration(days: 1),
      content: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onVerticalDragStart: (_) => debugPrint("no can do!"),
        child: Text("Hi! Don't try to dismiss me.\n\n\n"),
      )
    );

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
  }
```

[image: SnackBar less dismissable]

I even tried to simply place the `SnackBar` widget directly into the `Scaffold`'s `bottomsheet` - however the results were the same, even wrapping the `GestureDetector` around the `SnackBar`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Builder(builder: (context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => showSnackbar(context),
      child: Text("Show snackbar"),
    );
  }),
  );
}

void showSnackbar(context) {
  Scaffold.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("I am here"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ))
      .closed
      .then((reason) {
       if (reason == SnackBarClosedReason.swipe)
         showSnackbar(context);
  });
}
```

Comment: This also creates a fun "Whack a SnackBar!" game.

Comment: Haha. But it is going to be difficult to keep the snackbar alive without playing with source code. So, it is a work around and you can give a Duration of like 1 day so that it won't get dismissed except when user does.

Comment: Nah it's a better workaround then I could come up with which was basically replying with "nope".